# How to set-up django-registration that an account needs to be manually activated?

Tags: django, registration

How to set-up django-registration that an account needs to be manually activated by an admin?

After the account-holder clicks in the link in the e-mail I would like that an e-mail is sent to the admin, and he also needs to click a link and only then the account would be active.

Is it possible with django-registration, or do I need to use something else, and what to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

django-registration allows you to write a [custom backend](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/backend-api.html) to handle custom activation needs.

So what you'd do is create your own backend, implementing the `register` and `activate` yourself.

Here's an example of how you could implement the `register` function:

```
def register(self, request, **kwargs):
    username, email, password = kwargs['username'], kwargs['email'], kwargs['password1']
    if Site._meta.installed:
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
    else:
        site = RequestSite(request)
    new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
                                                                password, site, 
                                                                send_email=False)
    # send an email to the admins with user information
    send_new_user_notification(new_user) # you would write this function
    signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                 user=new_user,
                                 request=request)
    return new_user
```

The key point is to make sure `send_email` is set to false; that will prevent the user from getting an activation link. Then you can decide whether the email sent to the admins has an activation link or if you're content with them going to admin and just checking the "Active" box.

If you use `AuthenticationForm` from `django.contrib.auth` then it will automatically reject users whose `is_active` is False, but if you're not using that then make sure to run the following check for any request where an active user is required:

```
def restricted_view(request):
    if request.user and request.user.is_active:
        #continue with the code
```

You can also write your own decorator (look at `@login_required` for pointers). Note that `@login_required` does *not* check for `is_active`.